# Is outbound data that is sent to the user also encrypted in an SSL connection?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption

The obvious use case for SSL is protecting sensitive data a user is sending to a website, such as credit card details. Does it work in reverse so that when a website is sending data to the client's browser, is it encrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inbound and outbound data, after handshake are typically protected by a symmetric cipher. They are protected nonetheless providing confidentiality of the content.

See [RFC-5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) [Section 7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7) for details of what this entails.

Answer (score 0):

It's encrypted and secured in various other ways in both directions.